# Prononciation de « pour quoi »

Tags: prononciation, pronoms-interrogatifs

> Tu es venu pour quoi faire ?

Est-ce qu'on prononce « pour quoi » comme « pourquoi » ?

Comment: Moi, oui! Sauf... si ça m énerve! Alors je force une pause entre pour et quoi et entre quoi et faire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pronounced the same way. But the meaning is different:

"Pourquoi" is more about the cause and "pour quoi" the purpose.

"Pour quoi faire" can also be formulated "pour faire quoi". Which helps making the nuance more obvious if relevant.

Answer (score 1):

They are homonyms but the meanings are different: "*pourquoi*" means "*why*" and "*pour quoi*" means "*what for*". But they are effectively pronounced exactly the same way.

Comment: Merely homophones, wouldnt' you say?

Answer (score 1):

"Tu es venu pourquoi faire" n'a aucun sens en français; à partir du moment où on est convaincu de cela il n'y a plus à se poser de question sur des différences de sens.

Comment: Ce que vous dites n'est pas faux, mais vous ne répondez pas à la question qui portait sur la prononciation.

Comment: @petitrien Vrai, ce n'est pas une bien bonne réponse.